# Wordpress goes blank after publishing new content?

Tags: wordpress

So out of no where after clicking the publish button the page just goes blank...

The url at the top is:
http://www.brightboxstudios.com/sociabulls/wp-admin/post.php

What's good news is it still posts the content :)

Not great at coding so details rock :)

Comment: Make that anything I change, even activating a plug-in or updating..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blank page usually means Apache failed. Check your [error logs](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/562). You'll probably find a line that starts with:

```
PHP Fatal error:
```

You can also [display your errors](http://itslennysfault.com/force-php-to-show-all-errors-or-save-them-to-a-log-for-trouble-shooting) on the screen instead of looking at the log.

Comment: Ok well it looks like having this in functions.php made this happen.

    <?php
    if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
        register_sidebar(array(
            'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<div class="title">',
        'after_title' => '</div>',
    ));
    ?>

Comment: You have a trailing coma (`,`): `'</div>', ));`

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same error, when I update the site content and press update it goes to /wp-admin/post.php and this appears as blank page.

It is solved by:

- I removed all the spaces at the end of functions.php file, I had included a widget and there were some spaces in between older content and new widget function, when I removed the spaces everything is working fine.

**if that don't work then**
 - go into wp-config.php and find this "define('WP_DEBUG', false);"

- change its value, if it is flase, make it true or if it is true change it to false.

And everything must work Good.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
There will be many reasons for blank page, you have not mention version for wp, php etc.

To solve wordpress blank page issue follow the steps
```

1. disable all plugin and try (if there is an error in plugins then enable 1 by 1)
2. switch to default theme and try (if there is an error in theme)
3. rename .htaccess and param-link to default (page/post id)